# Journey builder skip steps (I think)

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a flow for a client, with a split, a send email, and Update contact..
But when I look at the overview, I dont understand how, someone can skip the Send Email, and go directly to the date contact step instead. (note the same mail is used in multiple step, some of them work, others not)

[image: Flow]

And is there any easy way to see who the 25 people in the last update contact is?

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to insert (a) a decision split activity prior to the Email Activity and define your criteria to skip the email, then (b) use a Join Activity to re-unite the Contact back to the branch.

Note that when you do so, a Wait Period Activity will automatically be added after the Decision Split Activity which you can safely remove after configuring the Join Activity. Refer to screenshot below.

[image: Join Activity]

To answer your second question, you can't preview which individual records reached an Activity, you will need to use another Update Contact Data Activity to update a DE so you can identify who reached that Activity.

Comment: You miss understand me, i DONT want it to skip a mail, but if you look at my picture, you can see that 1,3,5 decision split have skipt sending the email and gone straight to Update Contact Data

Comment: Perhaps the email failed to send. Check the tracking activity from Email App > Tracking > Sends then expand the Journey Builder tree on the left and select journey and version. To debug why a send would be failing, preview the email using the Generate Preview feature in the email app and select your Event Source DE.

Comment: I have validated the email against the Sendable Data Extension with no errors. Number 2,3,4,5 in the decision split are all the same emails. Number 2 and 4 works.

Comment: Validating the email alone isn't going to help you. You should try using Generate Preview to preview the records from your Event Source DE.

Comment: Still no error. I kind have a feeling that its just the preview of the Journey that dosnt show the number, but people have gotten the mail

Comment: How odd. I'm curious to learn why you would be sending the same email in each branch anyway — isn't the decision split redundant here?

Comment: the users come with an attribute (country) called version: It can be DK, CN, US, DE, UK.. Four of them will get an English mail, so the split is made so i can see how many from each country go through the flow